# How to loop through api using Python to pull records from specific group of pages

Tags: python-3.x, api, for-loop

I wrote a Python script that pulls json data from api.  The api has 10k records.

As I set up my script, I was only pulling 10 pages, (each page contains 25 items), so it worked fine, dump everything in a .csv and also put everything into a mysql db.

When I ran, what I thought would be my last test and pulled, should I say - attempted to pull the data from all 500 pages, got an **internal server error**.  So researched that and think it is because I am pulling all this data at once.  The api documentation is kind of crapy, can find any rate limit info, anyway...

Since this is not my api, I though a quick solution would be just to run my script, let it pull the data from the first 10 pages, then the second 10 pages, 3rd 10 pages etc.

For obvious reasons I can't show all the code, but below are the basics/snippets.  It is pretty simple, just grad the url, manipulate it a bit so I can add the Page#, then count the number of pages, then loop through and grab the data content.

Could someone help by explaining/showing how I can run/loop through my url, get the content from pages 1-10, then next loop through and get the content from pages 11-21 and so on?

Any insight, suggestions, examples would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_now = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

# Make our Request
def main_request(baseurl, x, endpoint, headers):
    r = requests.get(baseurl + f'{x}' + endpoint, headers=headers)
    return r.json()


    # determine how many pages are needed to loop through, use for pagination
def get_pages(response):
#   return response['page']['size']
    return 2  


def parse_json(response):
    animal_list = []
    for item in response['_embedded']['results']:
        animal_details = {
           'animal type': item['_type'],
           'animal title': item['title'],
           'animal phase': item['type']['value']
        }
        animal_list.append(animal_details)
    return animal_list


animal_main_list = []
animal_data = main_request(baseurl, 1, endpoint, headers)
    for x in range(1, get_pages(animal_data) + 1):
        print(x)
        mainList.extend(parse_json(main_request(baseurl, x, endpoint, headers)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.  Using the range function and the f{x} in my url.  Set the range in a for loop and it updates the url.  I used sleep.time to slow the retrieval down